# Ionic/AngularJS & Wordpress API

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm somewhat new to the JS world, so I'm struggling a bit as to what I did wrong.  My sample data from wordpress API is not working.  Any ideas what I did wrong:

```
app.controller('FeedCtrl', function($http, $scope,     $ionicLoading) {
  console.log("Loading FeedCtrl");

  $scope.stories = [];

  function loadStories(params, callback) {
    $http.get('http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/freshly-pressed/', {params: params})
  .success(function(response) {
    var stories = [];
    angular.forEach(response.data.children, function(child) {
      stories.push(child.data);
    });
    callback(stories);
  });
  }

  $scope.loadOlderStories = function() {
var params = {};
if ($scope.stories.length > 0) {
  params['after'] = $scope.stories[$scope.stories.length - 1].name;
}
 loadStories(params, function(olderStories) {
  $scope.stories = $scope.stories.concat(olderStories);
  $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
});
  };

  $scope.loadNewerStories = function() {
var params = {'before': $scope.stories[0].name};
loadStories(params, function(newerStories) {
  $scope.stories = newerStories.concat($scope.stories);
  $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simplified example with your data.

Click the 'Load more' button to retrieve some posts. You should see a list with the title and the author of a post.

**EDIT**: There appears to be some cross-domain request issues, that's why the 'Load stories' button won't work. Just try to reflect this code inside your controller, it should work.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('feedCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.stories = [];

    $scope.loadStories = function loadStories() {
      console.log('loading stories');
      $http.get('http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/freshly-pressed/')
        .then(function onSuccess(response) {
          console.log(response);
          $scope.stories = response.data.posts;
        }, function onFailed(error) {
          console.error('Error:', error)
        });
  
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  
  <div ng-controller="feedCtrl">
    <button data-ng-click="loadStories()">Load stories</button>

    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="story in stories">Title: {{ story.title }} - {{ story.author.first_name }} {{ story.author.last_name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

*Normally we wouldn't handle $http calls in our **angular.controller**. This needs to be done in an **angular.service**.*

Comment: Doesn't seem to be loading any data.  Am I missing something?  Sorry.

Comment: Could you check your console for any errors? Maybe you're getting something like: 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load'.

Comment: Not seeing any javascript errors, just a few CSS issues.

Comment: I've edited my post. The 'load stories' function on this page (Stack Overflow) doesn't work because of some cross-domain request errors. Could you try this 'simplified' chunk of code in your code and tell me how that works out?

Comment: Can you confirm that the event (button click for example) is fired?
If you open your console, do you see a log -> 'loading stories'?
(make sure that this `console.log('loading stories)` is in the beginning of the loadStories function.)